# Smooth scrolling to a row inside a scrollable table

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement a catalog of products. All the products are to be listed in a table that has overflow-y enabled. I need a way to implement a smooth scroll to a specific rows within the scrollable table. Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PHTsd/

Only one constraint here -  The page should not scroll: only the table should scroll

I tried a few methods like:
Chris Coyer's Smooth scroll

```
$(function() {   $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }   }); });
```

replacing `$('html,body')` with `$('table')` but to no avail.

Am I missing something? Is there a plugin that already implements this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you've added overflow:auto and a height to your tbody tag. Try using scrollTop() on that instead of the table. I'd say do one of the following:

If you want to scroll the tbody, then target that instead of the table itself- in other words, above you said you replaced $("html, body") with $("table"); you'd replace it instead with:

```
$("tbody");
```

If you don't plan on having a table header stick then target the table itself instead of the body, but you need to *adjust your CSS to set the overflow:auto property to the table instead of the tbody*.

Try this in the console, you'll see it works fine:

```
$("tbody").scrollTop(50);
```

You can replace the 50 with anything to see the effect it has. You will likely still have to fiddle with it but this should get you going in the right direction.

If you need more clarification, let me know and I'll help.

One more thing- *give your table an ID or class*, and target that:

```
<table id="someTable">
    <tbody>.....</tbody>
</table>

$("#someTable tbody").scrollTop(50);
```

This is a much safer way to do things!

Comment: This worked like a charm! This one bugged me for days.. Thank you for a quick and clear answer. I do  reference tables by ids but thanks for re-stating that too :) Also, the callback works great with the scrollTop. I have a nice smooth scrolling table going on now. Thanks again, and a happy new year to you!

Comment: Glad to help, happy new year :)